# I need to translate a quote

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, verbs, adjective

This quote is original: "Even to the question whether there can be only one truth, the answer is twofold"

I used Google translate to translate it to latin and this is what I got: "Etiam ad quaestionem an veritas una tantum esse possit, duplex est responsio"

I want this quote to be in latin and to be 100% correct in meaning and grammar as I am thinking to tattoo it. Could you please help me with translating it as well as explaining why we use "an veritas una tantum esse possit" instead of "an sit una tantum veritas"? Which sounds better etc? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Google Translate is unreliable for Latin: (e.g., *quaestio* is not a question).

Instead, I suggest the following:

> Potestne una tantum veritas esse?
> Etiam haec interrogatio duo responsa habet.

> Can there be only one truth?
> Even this question has two answers.

Or if you want a concise version:

> Potestne una tantum veritas esse?
> Duo responsa sunt.

> Can there be only one truth?
> There are two answers.